# Is it possible to make a textbox beside an equation in Beamer?

Tags: math-mode, alignment

Although it's really obvious what I substituted, I still want to add a box beside Line 4 to show what I substituted (e.g. Let `$u=1+9x^{4}$ \\ $du=36x^{3}$`)

[image: Example slide that shows the formula set: How do I place a box beside Line 4 that shows my substitution]

(Unrelated) Another question is why is it that when I try to View PDF, it's jumping up again to the 2nd slide.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.... Can you provide a `MWE` of what you tried?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you have two questions, that are not related, please consider opening a second question, especially when one is related to LaTeX code and the other to a PDF viewer.

Comment: Try with \usepackage{mathtools}` and `\Aboxed{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help of command `\boxed` from `amsmath` package I can reproduce (to some degree) image of your equation. If this is not what you like to have, please  clarify your question and on the first place provide MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 x  & = y + 1   \\     
    & = \boxed{a+b+c}
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

or maybe you lookinf for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 x  & = y + 1   \\     
    & = u-c   \qquad\boxed{\scriptsize
                            \begin{aligned}[t]  
                                u   & = 1+9x^4\\[-1ex]
                                du  & = 36x^3
                           \end{aligned}} \\
    & = a+1 \\
    & = \boxed{a+b+c}
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right, I was looking for that second one. Thanks for the help guys!